# Magento 2 move same element to multiple location

Tags: magento2

I am trying to move the "product.info.social" element to "product.info.addtocart.additional" and "product.info.addtocart" in product detail page using the "catalaog_product_view.xml" as

```
<move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.addtocart.additional" />
    <move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.addtocart" />
```

But it is only displaying in **"product.info.addtocart"** - means the move only works to **"product.info.addtocart"**. How could I move the "product.info.social" to both blocks?

Comment: please let me know if you have any issue

Comment: @Rakesh Thanks for the replay. But the syntax is correct. Still it is not moving. Do I need to give the aliases?

Answer (score 0):

**Both blocks have same templates so your code is correct and moving to one file,**

Both blocks have same template, **`product/view/addtocart.phtml`**

Please check block syntax for that,

For addtocart block

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

For additional block,

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```